# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError using update_attributes having created params hash myself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I’m trying to edit/update a model record using simple_form, but the form is not going to directly change a model field.  Instead, I offer a couple of check_box_tag fields that tell update what fields need changed.  As a result, update is not receiving a params[:device] hash that I can use to update the attributes.  I am attempting to create this hash, but am getting ForbiddenAttributesError when I issue the @device.update_attributes(params[:device]).

I believe my strong parameters list is correct.  If I allow one model field (name) to be processed in the edit view, I receive the expected params[:device] hash and everything works.  If I disable that field, because I don’t want it to be changed, then I need to create that hash myself and I receive the error.  When I look at the hash I created, it looks to me as equivalent to the one passed by the view.  I don’t understand why it is failing.

Environment is Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.1 on Windows 8.1 with RubyMine 6.3.

The form is:  <... needs correct formatting once working ...>

```
<%= simple_form_for @device do |f| %>
      <legend><%= controller.action_name.capitalize %> Device:</legend>
      <%= f.input :name, disabled: true %>
      <%= check_box_tag(:is_admin, 0, @device.admin?) %>
      <%= label_tag(:is_admin, "Make admin?") %>
      <%= check_box_tag(:chg_pwd) %>
      <%= label_tag(:chg_pwd, "Change password?") %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The params[:device] that I receive when I sent f.input :name, disabled: false and allow the view to generate params[:device] is:

```
ActionController::Parameters (3 element(s))
"{"name"=>"D105", "password"=>"D105Dvgr", "password_confirmation"=>"D105Dvgr"}"
```

And, everything works.

The params[:device] that I create is:

```
ActionController::Parameters (3 element(s))
"{"name"=>"D106", "password"=>"D106VdAd", "password_confirmation"=>"D106VdAd"}"
```

And, I receive Forbidden Attribute Error, even though I see no difference between the two.

The update is:  <... Code needs refactored, once it is working...>

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_device!

... other methods removed here ...

  def edit
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    # my_page = render_to_string controller: 'devices', action: 'edit', layout: "application"
  end

  def update
    authorize! :update, @device, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    pwd_msg = ""
    if params[:chg_pwd]
      pwd_gen = @device.device + SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(15).tr('lIO0=_\-', 'sxyzEUM').first(4)
      params[:device] = {name: @device.name} if params[:device].nil?
      params[:device][:password] = pwd_gen
      params[:device][:password_confirmation] = pwd_gen
      pwd_msg = ", new password is #{pwd_gen}"
    end
    if @device.update_attributes(params[:device])
      params[:is_admin] ? @device.add_role(:admin) : @device.remove_role(:admin)
      flash[:notice] = ["Device updated" + pwd_msg]
      redirect_to devices_path
    else
      @device.errors.messages.each do |key, value|
        flash[:alert] = ["Unable to update device"]
        @device.errors.messages.each do |key, value|
          flash[:alert] << key.to_s.capitalize + " " + value[0]
        end
      end
      redirect_to devices_path
    end
  end

  private

  def device_params
    params.require(:device).permit(:device, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :encrypted_password, :salt, :role_ids, :is_admin, :chg_pwd)  # TODO minimize when update is working
  end

end
```

The model is:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base

  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :device,
            presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 4 },
            uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false }
  validates :name,
            presence: true

  def remember_me
    true unless self.admin?
  end

  def admin
    self.add_role :admin
  end

  def not_admin
    self.remove_role :admin
  end

  def admin?
    self.has_role? :admin
  end
  def device?
    self.has_role? :device
  end
  def vip?
    self.has_role? :vip
  end

  def login=(login)
    @login = login
  end
  def login
    @login || self.device || self.email
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)  # Note one equal sign.  Strange but true.
      where(conditions).where(["lower(device) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

end
```

NEW INFORMATION:  I neglected to provide information I have in the ApplicationController.  This fix from Anton Trapp handles strong parameters for gems that aren't yet fully Rails 4 compatible:

```
  before_filter do
    resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
    method = "#{resource}_params"
    params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
  end
```

I have found that using the proposed solution of:

```
@device.update_attributes(device_params)
```

does not work if a model field is updated.  The result is "param not found: device".  It does work if no model field is update.  So, the whole issue begs the question of what is truly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to add the fields as attr_accessor to the model, but not the database, so that it could be used correctly within the form.

```
  attr_accessor :is_admin, :chg_pwd
```

And then modify the view to:

```
<%= simple_form_for @device do |f| %>
    <legend><%= controller.action_name.capitalize %> Device:</legend>
    <%= f.input :name, disabled: true %>
    <%= f.input :is_admin, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
    <%= f.input :chg_pwd, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then, due to the Application Controller code from Anton Trapp:

```
  before_filter do
    resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
    method = "#{resource}_params"
    params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
  end
```

I was able to update the fields in Device Controller as follows:

```
@device.update_attributes(params[:device])
```

Answer (score 5):

In `DevicesController#update` action, change

```
@device.update_attributes(params[:device])
```

To

```
@device.update_attributes(device_params)
```

As you are using `Rails 4.1`, you need to whitelist the attributes which you would like to be inserted/updated in database. As you passed the attributes directly to `update_attributes` method without permitting them you received `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

**UPDATE**

To resolve `param not found: device`:

```
  def device_params
    if params[:device]
      params.require(:device).permit(:device, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :encrypted_password, :salt, :role_ids, :is_admin, :chg_pwd)  # TODO minimize when update is working 
    end
  end
```

Comment: Okay, the change makes total sense and works.  I still wonder, though, why it worked the way it was when a model field was involved?  Do you know that?  Thanks...

Comment: `why it worked the way it was when a model field was involved?` means? Which model field? Do you mean this same code worked in any case?

Comment: In the edit view, if I use "f.input :name, disabled: false", then params[:device] is sent to the update action with params[:davice][:name] set.  In that case, the update action worked as I had it.  If, instead, I use "f.input :name, disabled: true", so that the name field cannot be changed, than params[:device] is nil.  In order to update_attributes, I built params[:device] as shown.  Both hashes are equivalent.  But, I received ForbiddenAttributeError on the hash I built even though the one that the edit view built for me worked using @device.update_attributes(params[:device]).

Comment: Do you mean to say that, with `disabled: false` option on name field, when *you key in a new device name* and submit the form. The name of the device gets  updated successfully and with no `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` errors at all?

Comment: No.  I am editing an existing device.  I don't want the name changed.  So, I want disabled: true.  But, that means that no model fields change, so no params[:device] get passed.  If I set disabled: false, params[:device][:name] gets passed whether it changes or not and the whole thing works as I coded it.

Comment: See new information at the end of the question.  It turns out the fix does not actually work if there IS a model field to be updated.  It does work if there IS NOT a model field to be updated...  Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: `It does work if there IS NOT a model field to be updated` means what? `Curiouser and curiouser` ?? Read my updated answer for `param not found: device` error. Next thing `No. I am editing an existing device. I don't want the name changed. So, I want disabled: true. But, that means that no model fields change, so no params[:device] get passed.`, Then why are you calling `update_attributes` in first place if you don't even plan to update anything?

Comment: Voted this answer up because it surely helped me focus my efforts.