# Rails ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError в simple_form nested_fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, simple-form, nested-attributes, activemodel

I experience a trouble while saving simple_form.fields_for - forbidden attributes error

'create' action in bookings controller looks so:

```
    def create
        ...
        new_params = params[:booking]
        new_params[:user_attributes] = new_params[:user_attributes].merge({"password"=>"osmsmsmsm32"}) # password is temp stuff to bypass User save validation
        @booking = Booking.new

        @booking.update(params)
        # however @booking.user.update(params[:booking][:user_attributes]) gives the same error
        ...
    end
    ...

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:arrived_at, :departured_at, :arrival_address, 
              :departure_address, :arrival_city, :departure_city, 
              :reservation_cost, :total_additional_cost, :user_attributes, :user_id, :garage_id, 
               user_attributes: [:id, :name, :surname, :email, :phone], 
               garage_attributes: [:id] 
                                        )
    end
===========================

      Booking:
      belongs_to :user
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
===========================

    ##In model User:
      has_many :bookings
```

However `@booking.user.save & @booking.save` in irb console with same params are successfully saveable and true is passed, without any **Forbidden Attribute error**.

Where is this Forbidden attribute come from? I am sure I allowed all the attrs I send in the form, and I think I use accepts_nested_attributes_for properly, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Just Define your user_attributes inside controller private method as per below:

```
private
  def user_params
    params.require(
      :user
    ).permit(
        :first_name,
        :last_name,
        :job_title
      )

  end
```

if you are working with nested filed just add nested attributes inside this attributes like below:

```
    private
      def user_params
        params.require(
          :user
        ).permit(
            :first_name,
            :last_name,
            :job_title,
            addresses_attributes: [:address_1, :address_2]
          )

      end
```

write nested attributes by take in mind your model associations,
Hope this will work for you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However it  is already done like that. But surprisingly not works, that's why I surprised.

Comment: can you please write rails version of your project, and you are building user object inside your new action of controller right?

Comment: refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990103/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-using-update-attributes-having-created-par